# Is it haram to say YOLO, given that we believe in the Day of Resurrection?

Tags: halal-haram, day-of-judgement

We all know that we live twice, as in the day of resurrection. The term YOLO shouldn't be believed in by Muslims as it denies this, but sometimes I use it only as an expression without taking in its meaning to heart or anything.  For example, if my friend says 'no way' if I told him that I went skydiving (just an example, didn't happen IRL) and he asks me why, I say 'YOLO' to show that it was a once in a lifetime great and thrilling experience and indirectly saying 'just do it'

In such a case, is it allowed? As neither I nor my Muslim friends take the meaning seriously here.

Comment: It is good you are concerned about it and you are worried about things like that. Where in todays world most of the muslims just don't care even about their prayers. I really appreciate that.

Comment: It is all about the intention and your definition about the word. If the person understand what you are trying to express then there is no problem.

Answer (score 3):

Wa alaikum salaam

### All perfect praise be to Allah

> وَقَالُوا إِنْ هِيَ إِلَّا حَيَاتُنَا الدُّنْيَا وَمَا نَحْنُ
>   بِمَبْعُوثِينَ
>
> And they say, "There is none but our worldly life, and we will not be
>   resurrected."

( Surah al an'aam verse 29.)

Allahu a'lam it's like youre rejecting the verses from the Quran completely by saying yolo. So, to be on safe side avoid this as much as possible even though you don't mean it.

I read somewhere:
*The non muslims say YOLO

So, Do all the misdeeds this dunya has to offer.

The muslim says YOLO(in this world)

So, Make salaah go on hajj and prove you believe.*

So, it all depends on what you mean by it. If you don't mean to say that there is no life hereafter than you are not doing any kufr. Now, by your question and your use. **I will still advice you to avoid it and be on safe side**. 
Though i am not a mufti so i cannot declare but i suspect it to be makrooh.

Because

> Al-Bukhaari and Muslim narrated from Abu Hurayrah that the Messenger
>   of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: **“ A person
>   may speak a word, not realizing what he is saying, and he will fall
>   because of it into the Fire further than the distance between the East
>   and West.”**

Allah says (interpretation of the meaning):

> “Not a word does he (or she) utter but there is a watcher by him ready
>   (to record it)” [50:18]

### Allah knows Best

Comment: I think you must not forget about the intention and the definition of the expression the one saying it has and what the one hearing the expression understand.

Comment: Thats exactly why it is not kufr brother. If he had meant it it would had been straight kuffar. But as he doesnot mean it, but it sounds like it and its usual meaning are also against islam. Thats why i THINK it is makrooh. Although i have wrote i have no authority to declare it. I just THINK so.

Comment: I see your point. I myself do not use that expression. It also depends on what language one is speaking. And as we know we use language to express ourselves differnetly which makes it hard for me to so it's makroh. I tend to dislike those terms but I'd be very cautious on calling it makroh just for sake. And in this case you only live once (in this donya) . Now there are other ways of expression oneself, for instance you could say "come on let's have some fun before we get old and tired." Then the question will arise who said that you are going to get old? you see my point. expressions..

Comment: Subhanallah... I agree 100% and i am saying it 3rd time that i am not mufti and i have no authority to declare it makrooh. But, i can see that it will be better to avoid it(as you also said). And things which are better to be avoided are actually termed as makrooh. So, anyway this is only my opinion based on my little understanding. May Allah guide us all.

Comment: I saw you mentioning that for the third time now brother ;)

Comment: @azam Bolded. Jazakallah